# Timer fired ad nauseam (native v8natives.js:1582)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance

I have a website that loads very slow. Today I have done a test with the Timeline included in the Chrome Tools for Developers and I have seen that during about 9 seconds there is a Timer firing in a JS called v8natives.js. I have checked my Wordpress plugins and none of them are loading this library. I don't know why this library is loading and what it is used for. Anyone knows something about this JS?

I have tried also deleting some Javascript calls, deactivate plugins... But nothing happens.

The website is http://www.laparabolica.es

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on these results:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120704_SN_10Z5/1/details/

It would appear that the web server is taking a long time (11.388 seconds in this case) to respond. (See Time to First Byte). I can't see v8natives.js in this equation ( Pretty sure this is something to do with Chrome's Javascript engine).

Since it's taking 11.388 seconds to receive the first byte of your site it can't be any javascript slowing this down...

Comment: Uhmm. Thanks for the test, Lee. You must be right, v8natives.js shall be a Chrome's library for its JS engine. I have contact with my hosting service. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am experiencid exactly the same since a while and it's not hosting issue.